# What graphics card for ASUS P5Q Deluxe Intel P45 Motherboard?

Tags: graphics-cards, upgrade

I have an old computer with ASUS P5Q Deluxe Intel P45 Motherboard which currently is using GForce 550 Ti graphics card which I gave to my son to play games like Minecraft, Roblox, Gary's Mode etc but recently he get more into more advanced games which require better graphics card.

I have tried to install XFX Radeon HD6870 which I have used few years back but for some reason it did not worked with that mobo (no signal to the monitor).

My question what will be good/max card which can be used with that mobo? There is 750W PSU so it should be fine to handle anything from 5 years back ;)

PS.

CPU is Core2Quad Q9650 (Yorkfield)

Comment: What's your budget?  You could theoretically put a 3090, so price is key :D.

Comment: @Salocor somewhere between $100-$160

Comment: Alright I'll find something in that price range

Comment: Hm, in theory the Hd6870 should just work on that board. 
I'D suggest to do some troubleshooting before purchasing a new GPU.

 - Did you connect the extra power cables to the GPU?
 - Does the GPU work in another computer?
 - Did you uninstall the Nvidia drivers before installing the AMD GPU?

Answer (score 1):

The GTX 970 looks like a good card.  It gets 50% on UserBenchmark.  My Radeon HD 6950 gets 18% and can play AAA titles at decent framerates, so 50% should be more than enough.  On eBay, you can get a GTX 970 for around $160 if you do some searching/bidding.

Comment: Any particular reason why XFX Radeon HD6870 on that mobo will not provide signal to the monitor?

Comment: I’d check the comment that skippy left on the original post.